# Can I safely advertise an open position in my company through my LinkedIn account

Tags: hiring-process, linkedin, social-media

Recently, an analyst on our Information Security team working in the SOC quit for greener pasture at another company. I work in a different, but very related role as an IT Auditor. I interface with the members of the IT Security almost daily in completing my work.

The IT Security team is looking for a replacement for the person that left. I participated in interviews of candidates for this open position, and the last handful that applied were unsuitable - inadequate technical skills, poor communication ability, behavioral red flags at interview etc.

I have many personal friends in addition to past colleagues in my LinkedIn professional network working in the InfoSec profession that I feel would be great fit for this open position at my company. I would feel comfortable in recommending them.

**However, is it Ok for me to use my LinkedIn account, a personal account, to advertise this position on my behalf of my company?**

Answer (score 10):

**Short Answer:**  Ask HR or the hiring manager of the IT Security team.  Or both.

In this case it's best not to act unilaterally.  If you outline to the hiring manager that you want to do this, then they can give you direction on whether or not this is a good idea.  It also may be worth running it by HR to ensure that there aren't any policies in place that you are not aware of and may fall foul of.

All we here can give you opinions, the best way to ensure that you are doing the right thing *in your organisation* is to ask those who have the authority to answer.

Comment: Many organisations will, themselves, advertise the position on LinkedIn and will probably be very grateful if you share that advertisement with your network. (But ask first, just in case).

Comment: I think this is the only objectively correct answer: check with your company. In most cases, they will be quite happy that they can take advantage of an employee's established network to fill a position, but it needs to be 'the company's decision' to do so.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Jane's answer, if they have posted the job on LinkedIn, or somewhere else that you can link to, then there should be no problem with you sharing it with your LinkedIn contacts.

Also, if you know a contact who might be a good fit, you can always send them a message mentioning the position, and offer to pass their resume directly to the hiring manager, with your recommendation, a potential win for both of you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it Ok for me to use my LinkedIn account, a personal account, to
>   advertise this position on my behalf of my company?

If your company has already advertised the role then you can share this on LinkedIn or other social media, in much the same way as you can share anything else that has been published.

If your company is smart then they will **love** you doing this, as referrals are on of the most reliable ways of finding competent new staff.

On a side note, if a friend comes to interview then you should not be an interviewer both for professional reasons and so that you don't damage your friendship if they don't get the job.